# PostgreSQL table does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
drop table Employee;   

 CREATE TABLE Employee
    (   EmployeeID integer,
        FirstName varchar(24),
        LastName varchar(24),
        Email varchar(48),
        PhoneNumber varchar(12),
        HotelID integer
        PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID),
    );

    INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1, ‘James’, ‘Jenkins’, ‘jj@gmail.com’, ’0412181111’, 1);
    INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (22, ‘Roy’, ‘Bond’, ‘jb@gmail.com’, ‘0418246192’, 1);
    INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (14, ‘Rachel’, ‘Green’, ‘rg@gmail.com’, ‘0468129367’, 1);
    INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (96, ‘Eddard’, ‘Stark’, ‘es@gmail.com’, ‘0458192716’, 1);
    INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (77, ‘Anna’, ‘Nguyen’, ‘an@gmail.com’ , ‘0418238694’, 1);
```

Error: "psql:employee:1: ERROR:  table "employee" does not exist"

What is the way that the error can be fixed?

Link to the entire doc if anyone wants to take a look: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r4E7yz4XJxLmO3rmkH4YBVOGfYN5PkhcDSJUyuy7qxw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: References hotel?

Comment: @Strawberry, even as an independent table, it still shows the does not exist error. I copied this one out of the database

Comment: Works fine for me http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5e44c

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh fixed the tag, thanks for pointing that out for me

Answer (score 0):

Your create statement has a comma(,) missing before declaring the primary key. Therefore the table is not getting created. This this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(   EmployeeID integer,
FirstName varchar(24),
LastName varchar(24),
Email varchar(48),
PhoneNumber varchar(12),
HotelID integer,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID),
FOREIGN KEY (HotelID) REFERENCES Hotel
);
```

Comment: That wasnt the issue, i added the comma in the create statement but there is no difference

Comment: What did you change in the code, i couldnt find it?

Comment: can you post your create statement form Hotel table?

Comment: try replacing your employee create query with my query, it should work

Comment: it didnt work, here is the error  `psql:employee:1: ERROR:  table "employee" does not exist
psql:employee:15: NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "employee_pkey" for table "employee"
CREATE TABLE
psql:employee:16: ERROR:  column "‘james’" does not exist
psql:employee:17: ERROR:  column "‘roy’" does not exist
psql:employee:18: ERROR:  column "‘rachel’" does not exist
psql:employee:19: ERROR:  column "‘eddard’" does not exist
psql:employee:20: ERROR:  column "‘anna’" does not exist`

Comment: Those single quotes are not recognized as string quotation mark by any computer language that I know of. You need to change them to `'`.

Answer (score 0):

The table `Employee` might not be already created in your database when you are trying to run above snippet. Always have an IF EXISTS check before dropping a table or stored procedure or function.

Your drop query should be.

```
drop table if exists `Employee`;
```

Comment: the backticks are invalid in Postgres (and btw: Postgres **does** support transactional DDL - if autocommit is turned off, rweise's answer is correct - you might need a commit to make the create or drop permananet)